# how to get an ordered json file from firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ive used firebaase recyclerview , and populated it with a json uploaded .
i have the items listed in ordered in the JSON file and wish to recieve them in the same order. However every time I get it jumbled in my app . How to solve this ?

```
public class NoticesFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mNoticesList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
//    private ProgressDialog vProgress;
    private View rootview;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Notices,NoticeViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;


    public NoticesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notices, container, false);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Wait While Load , It May Take Some Time ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notice");

        mNoticesList = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.notices_list);

        mNoticesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(  getActivity() ) );

        mNoticesList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        return rootview;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

         firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Notices, NoticeViewHolder>(

                Notices.class,
                R.layout.list_view_row,
                NoticeViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(NoticeViewHolder viewHolder, Notices model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setRefertext(model.getRefer());
                    viewHolder.setDatetext(model.getDate());
                    viewHolder.setLink(model.getLink());
            }
        };



        mNoticesList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    public static class NoticeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        final View mView;
        private String link;
        private Intent myIntent;
         public NoticeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

             mView = itemView;
             mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     try {
                         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
                         mView.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                     } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                         Toast.makeText(mView.getContext(),"No Activity found to handle the request ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 }
             });

        }
        public void setRefertext(String refertext){
            TextView referText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.refer_text);
            referText.setText(refertext);
        }

        public void setDatetext (String datetext){
            TextView dateText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            dateText.setText(datetext);

        }

        public void setLink (String link){
            this.link = link;

        }

    }







}
```

What shall I do so that the ordered JSON that I uploaded onto firebase? I want get back the items in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is by definition unordered. So the way the items are present in the JSON file you upload is lost as it is persisted to the database.

To order data, you'd use Firebase's `orderBy...` methods when retrieving the data. For example if your notices have a timestamp property, you could get them ordered in the recycler view with:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Notices, NoticeViewHolder>(

    Notices.class,
    R.layout.list_view_row,
    NoticeViewHolder.class,
    mDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp")

) {
```

I recommend spending some time in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/), specifically the [section on ordering and filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).